# Conditional formatting based on another cell's colour

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a google spreadsheet with numerical data and month names on top.

Is there any way to copy conditional formatting from the bottom row (numerical) to the top one (month names)?

For example, highlight 'April' in green and 'August' in red?

Formatting top row based on the values of the bottom row won't work, since data can change a lot.

[image: g-sheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
function copyColors() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var cA=sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(),2,1,sh.getLastColumn()-1).getBackgrounds();
  sh.getRange(1,2,cA.length,cA[0].length).setBackgrounds(cA);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great! Is there any way to automate it? So colours of months will be updated as last row is updated?

Comment: It's just a SUM of previous rows. It could be moved down, if more rows will be added in the future.

Comment: Okay, then how are rows added?

Comment: Manually right now, calculations are done in python. Planning to add pandas to g-sheets integration later.

Comment: Manual edits can be detected via onEdit() trigger.  [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)